# SQLite не находит данные

Tags: android, sqlite

Имеется база данных с городами. Я пытаюсь проверить есть ли город в базе данных, но всегда получаю res==0. Если составить запрос, который выводит все города в logcat, то в нем корректно выводятся все города.
Вот собственно код:

```
public byte checkWord(String city) {
    if (used.contains(city))
        return ALREADY_USED;
    // !
    city = "Рим";
    // !
    String[] args = new String[] { "city=" + city };
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  cities WHERE ?", args);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int res = c.getInt(0);
        if (res == 1) {
            c.close();
            return OK;
        }
    }
    return CITY_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

В чём может быть причина?

P.S. Рим в базе данных точно есть)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
String[] args = new String[] { city };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  cities WHERE city=?", args);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я раньше так пробовал, но у меня вылетало с  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters. Может быть я тогда что-то перепутал.